# User does not have authority/permission despite being db2 dba admin user

Tags: db2, privileges, db2-luw

On Db2 v11.1 Enterprise Edition on Linux/x86-64 I checked authorities for my current connected user:

```
select
   granteetype,
   dbadmauth,
   securityadmauth,
   dataaccessauth,
   accessctrlauth
from syscat.dbauth
where grantee = 'ADM1'
```

and from output I see this user is super user on database:

```
GRANTEETYPE DBADMAUTH SECURITYADMAUTH DATAACCESSAUTH ACCESSCTRLAUTH
----------- --------- --------------- -------------- --------------
U           Y         Y               Y              Y
```

When I try to do one of the following three tasks I always get permission errors.

```
db2 "select * from sysibmadm.snaptab_reorg"
```

> SQL1092N  The requested command or operation failed because the user
> ID does not have the authority to perform the requested command or
> operation.  User ID: "ADM1".

```
db2 "CREATE REGULAR TABLESPACE tbs1"
```

> SQL0552N  "ADM1" does not have the privilege to perform
> operation "CREATE TABLESPACE".  SQLSTATE=42502

```
db2 "CREATE bufferpool bp1"
```

> SQL0552N  "ADM1" does not have the privilege to perform operation
> "CREATE BUFFERPOOL".  SQLSTATE=42502

Why does 'ADM1' user get permission errors?

Regards

Comment: Has the database been restored , and had previously been in a different db2-instance? (check distinct grantor in syscat.dbauth).  Is your account a member of the configured SYSADM_GROUP in linux? Is the database created with 'restrictive' option?

Comment: User was not in one of the SYSxxx groups required by commands. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked documentation [create tablespace](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=statements-create-tablespace), [create bufferpool](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=statements-create-bufferpool) and [snaptab_org table](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=views-snap-get-tab-reorg-table-reorganization-snapshot) and all of them require one of the SYSxxx authority, but user "ADM1" does not have one of SYSxxx authorities.

```
select * from table
(sysproc.auth_list_authorities_for_authid ('ADM1', 'U')) as t
where authority like 'SYS%'

AUTHORITY D_USER D_GROUP D_PUBLIC ROLE_USER ROLE_GROUP ROLE_PUBLIC D_ROLE
--------- ------ ------- -------- --------- ---------- ----------- ------
SYSADM    *      N       *        *         *          *           *
SYSCTRL   *      N       *        *         *          *           *
SYSMAINT  *      N       *        *         *          *           *
SYSMON    *      N       *        *         *          *           *
```

P.S. I wrongly assumed that DBA authority is sufficient for those actions.